# Is it Possible to use RPC while writing Test cases for flows in corda?

Tags: testing, blockchain, corda

Not able to access RPC client while writing test cases for flows in corda

Comment: You can refer this question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51495748/in-the-corda-flow-testing-framework-how-can-i-get-an-rpc-connection-to-a-mock-n

Answer (score 0):

To test node RPC calls, you need to create integration tests using the node driver. See an example here: https://github.com/corda/cordapp-example/blob/release-V3/java-source/src/integrationTest/java/com/example/DriverBasedTests.java.